# How to recursively find attribute value on different level in java

Tags: java, java-8

Looking for a generic solution to find attribute value of a class on different level of hierarchy. The input to the method will be attribute name only (like "name") then I should be able to find value of that attribute.

The structure of my class is just like below:

```
class Student {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private List<Address> addresses;
    private Map<String, String> customAttributes;
}

class Address {
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private PhoneNumbers phoneNumbers;
    ...
    getter setter
}

class PhoneNumbers {
    private PhoneNumber phoneNumber1;
    private PhoneNumber phoneNumber2;
    ..
    getter setter
}

class PhoneNumber {
    private String code;
    private String number;
    ...
    getter setter
}
```

It's easy to find value on student level, in that case I can create map of <attribute, getter> and I will be able to find the value.

But in current scenario, there are different levels, custom attribute map and records are high in numbers (like 10,000 or more).

So the input to the method can be anything like:

```
private String getAttributeValue(String attributeName) {
    
}

var phoneNumber1 = new PhoneNumber("012", "233223");
var phoneNumber2 = new PhoneNumber("91", "23323223");
var phoneNumbers = new PhoneNumbers(phoneNumber1, phoneNumber2);

var address1 = new Address("city1", "state1", phoneNumbers);
var address2 = new Address("city123", "state1", phoneNumbers);

var customAttributes = Map.of(
    "attr1", "value1",
    "attr2", "value2"
);

var student = new Student(1, "xyz", List.of(address1, address2), customAttributes);

city -> city123
attr2 -> value2
code -> 012
number -> 23323223
```

Please help me here, if anyone has implemented the similar solution.

Comment: What would you like exactly to find? The different cities in all addresses of a single Student for example?

Comment: Hi @DavideLorenzoMARINO, in case of list like address, output should be (city or state) name with maximum length.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO I have updated my question with more explanation

Comment: @Abra Yes, I will pass attribute as "attr1" and it should return value1 as output

Comment: @Abra you can say input to the method getAttributeValue(Student student, String attribute) -> attribute can be of any level.

Comment: Every method needs to be written inside a class, i.e. `public class X { private method getAttributeValue(String attributeName) {} }` What is **X**? Is is `Student`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For generic way please take a look at Java's `Reflection` API, e.g. with:

```
final Field[] declaredFields = source.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
```

you can get all declared fields and use them to get value of particular field,  filter them by name or type etc. Using this you'll be able to build api like `getValueByName(object,"fieldName")` quite easily. You can even build support for nested attribute names like `getValueByName(addressObj,"phoneNumbers.code")`. For getting into deeper level you can go with recursion:

- Get fields on current level - search for required one for current segment, e.g. "phoneNumbers"
- Get value for this field and dive into recursion again to search for next segment, e.g. "code"

How to organise your further code depends on your requirements. There can be default "getter" reading the value of field in generic way + "custom getters" overriding the behavior for particular types like `List<String>`

Answer (score 0):

Note after the question update: The following is to find the maximum length. If needed to find the string with the maximum size the code must be updated removing the .length() and updating the succeding part taking in consideration that.

To get the maximum city length on all addresses you can do something like that:

```
public int maxLengthAddressCity() {
    return addresses.stream()
              .mapToInt(address -> address.getCity().length())
              .max();
}
```

Assuming that the property `phoneNumbers` in the class `Address` is of type `List<PhoneNumber>` instead of type `PhoneNumbers` to get the maximum phone number length:

```
public int maxLengthPhoneNumber() {
    return addresses.stream()
              .flatMap(address -> address.getPhoneNumbers())
              .mapToInt(phoneNumber -> phoneNumber.getPhone())
              .max();
}
```

Instead if you need a generic method you can use a JsonPath library. Convert your object to a json and use json expressions like:

```
 // To get the list of city lengths, then use a max function to extract the maximum value 
 $.addresses[*].city.length

 // To get the list of city lengths, then use a max function to extract the maximum value 
 $.addresses[*].phoneNumbers[*].phoneNumber.length
```

You can use the tool https://jsonpath.com/ to make some experiment on jsonPath and take a look of the jway library for java at this [link](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

Comment: Hi @DavideLorenzoMARINO, in first approach, how do I map attribute to caller method, it attribute is coming as "city" then maxLengthAddressCity() will be executed. But problem is creating mapper and filter based on coming attribute.
And I can not use second approach because of restriction but I can use ObjectMapper which I was thinking as my next step.

Comment: The first case is not parametric. You need to create a method for each need. If you need a parametric method you can use the second case or you can take use of Reflection